# Oracle: Merge multiple rows by date field

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have an oracle table that has multiple rows of data I am trying to merge based on a date field.

The data looks like this:

[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqWVL.png)

I'm trying to make the data look like this:

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8jid.png)

What would the query look look like to achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post sample data and desired results as text, not as images.  Preferrably as part of a reproducible example (DDL to create tables, DML to populate them, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you just want

```
select uid, date, 
       max(first_name) first_name,
       max(middle_name) middle_name,
       max(last_name) last_name
  from your_table
 group by uid, date;
```

That assumes that the sample data from the image is full of `null` values when data appears to be missing.